# Real algebraic subgroups action in the projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian closed normal real algebraic subgroup of the complex  projective linear group. Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. If the homogeneous space $X:=G/H$ is contained in the complex projective space.

1. Is the action of $G$ on $X$ linear (algebraic)?
2. Is $X$ closed in the complex projective space?

Comment: What do you mean that $G/H$ is contained in complex projective space?

Comment: Subset of $P^n$

Comment: You need to be more specific. How are you considering $G/H$ to be a subset of $P^n$?

Comment: I think $G/H$ is quasiprojective which makes it a locally closed subset of $P^n$.

Comment: I mean $G$ acts smoothly on $X$ and the orbit $G\cdot x\subset P^n$ where $x:=eH$.

Comment: This is still very unclear. You haven't explained why $G\cdot x \subset P^n$, much less why $G/H\subset P^n$.

Comment: Submanifold of the $P^n$. Maybe this is not necessary actually. I just wanted to say that $G$ is a closed abelian normal subgroup of the automorphism group of the projective space. So its orbits are submanifolds of $P^n$. But didn't want to assume that $G$ acts linearly on $X$

Comment: Do you know why the orbits are submanifolds of $P^n$? What you said above is incomplete.